# Angular JS script Works on Firefox does not work on IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement custom validation with `angular js`.

The following code runs perfectly on `FireFox` however `IE 11` throws an error

> Expected ':'

for the line `return scope.valFunc({value});`

Any ideas how to remedy that for `IE`? 
Thanks.

**Directive:**

```
crudApp.directive('customValidationFunction', function()  {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            valFunc: '&customValidationFunction'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller)  {
            const normalizedFunc = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                const $value = modelValue || viewValue;
                return scope.valFunc({$value});
            };
            controller.$validators.customValidationFunction = normalizedFunc;
        }
    };
});
```

**Validation Function**:

```
 //custom validation test 
    $scope.custValidationFunc = function($value) {
        if (!$value) {
            return true;
        }
        const lowVal = String($value).toLowerCase();
        return lowVal.indexOf("arnold") === -1 && lowVal.indexOf("sylvester") === -1;
    }
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="i_position" name="i_position" aria-describedby="i_position_help" placeholder="Enter your Position" ng-model="position"  custom-validation-function="custValidationFunc($value)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scope.valFunc({value})` is ES6 syntax & IE doesn't support it. You need to integrate Babel or simple change to `scope.valFunc({value: value})`

Comment: Ok thanks - it was actually `scope.valFunc({$value: $value})` that worked!